# Why doesn't save() work in Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I call `save()` on an object that already exists in my database and has a primary key defined.

Instead of updating the object, Sequelize tells me `id must be unique`. Why?

I don't want to have to say `update( {every,single,field,except,the,id})`. That's so tedious.

Here's my current code:

```
const instance = db.dbo__peach_payments_transactions.build(existingPayment);
return db.transaction( async (transaction) => {
  return instance.save();
});
```

---

I've also now tried:

```
return instance.update({fields: [
          'updated_at',
          'orders_id',
          'payment_states_id',
          'response_data',
          'token',
          'result',
          'reason_code',
          'reason_message',
          'price',
          'processed_at']});
      });
```

but this generates the **opposite** sql, instead of saving those fields, it excludes them giving me the error: `updated_at cannot be null` (even when it's not null) with this sql:

`"INSERT INTO "dbo"."peach_payments_transactions" ("peach_payments_transactions_id","created_at") VALUES ('7fb301e9-bb72-4a70-9ee5-0db1376e83e8','2016-07-11 13:48:20.137 +00:00') RETURNING *;"`

Comment: could you check if `instance.isNewRecord` has `false` value? How do you get the `instance`? With the `.find()` function?

Comment: I get the instance from the client (browser) when it calls my server. I'll try set isNewRecord now, thanks, that's not in the docs.

Comment: Yes, thanks, that works. Aw man, I wish the Sequelize guys would update their docs. I feel I'm battling a snowstorm with this library. And there's hardly anyone on Stackoverflow either :-(

Comment: I'm glad it worked! Could you mark my answer as correct as a favor? hehe :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you try setting `instance.isNewRecord` to `false` before sending it to the server?

Maybe sequelize is considering it a new record, therefore it tries to insert it instead of updating

Comment: If you want more points: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38304742/how-to-do-ordering-a-select-in-sequelize-correctly

Comment: Why is `isNewRecord` being set to true if it's coming from a `.findAll()`?