# Sequelize v6 Instance Reports New Record from Find

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I'm using Sequelize v6 and I have hooks that I want to run if a specific field within a table is updated. Thus, I'm using the instance's `update` method, instead of the Model's `update` method since it doesn't have insights into the previous values of a model (from what I can tell).

I get the instances from a `.findAll()`

```js
const records = await MyModel.findAll({
    where: {
      val0: requestBody.val0,
      val1: requestBody.val1,
    },
  })
```

Each one of the records returns has `isNewRecord: true`. Why is this?  It cause a real headache when I was attempting to update the record because it kept inserting new records instead of updating my existing one.  I didn't realize it was happening until I saw [Why doesn't save() work in Sequelize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38308395/why-doesnt-save-work-in-sequelize/38309135#38309135) on SO. Shouldn't this default to "false" since it came from a finder function?

Below is an entire example of my function:

```js
import express from 'express'

import Database from '../../database'
import { MyModel } from '../../models'

export default async (
  request: express.Request, 
  response: express.Response
): Promise<void> => {
  const requestBody = request.body
  const records = await MyModel.findAll({
    where: {
      val0: requestBody.val0,
      val1: requestBody.val1,
    },
  })
 }

  try {
    await Database.pool.transaction(async (t) => {
      const taskList: Promise<[affectedCount: number]>[] = []
      for (const entry of requestBody) {
        const currentSettings = records.find((instance) => {
          return instance.val2 === entry.val2
        })
        const allSame: boolean[] = [
          entry.val0 === currentSettings.val0,
          entry.val1 === currentSettings.val1,
          entry.val2 === currentSettings.val2,
        ]
        if (allSame.every((x) => x)) {
          continue
        } else {
          currentSettings.isNewRecord = false // <== Mandatory Line otherwise 
          //the update will insert a new record instead of modifying this one
          await currentSettings.update(entry, { transaction: t })
        }
      }

      await Promise.all(taskList)
    })

    // Returned updated data
    response.json({
      data: await MyModel.findAll({
        where: {
          val0: requestBody.val0,
          val1: requestBody.val1,
        },
      }),
    })
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('error updating model', err)
    response.status(500).json({ error: err })
  }
}
```